# Why am I getting an error while trying to install gym openai using pip?

Tags: python, macos, pip, python-imaging-library, openai-gym

I have tried to install gym using pip command and here is the error I get. I need help with it.

It also gives an error for pillow.'Running setup.py install for Pillow ... error'
I am very new at using pip for installation. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I already tried upgrading PIP and pillow but another error is found :
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
gym 0.18.0 requires Pillow<=7.2.0, but you have pillow 8.1.0 which is incompatible.

```
(base) Meets-MacBook-Pro:~ meetpandya$ sudo pip install gym
WARNING: The directory '/Users/meetpandya/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting gym
  Downloading gym-0.18.0.tar.gz (1.6 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.6 MB 4.1 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from gym) (1.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.10.4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy-1.20.0rc2-py3.9-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg (from gym) (1.20.0rc2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyglet<=1.5.0,>=1.4.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from gym) (1.5.0)
Collecting Pillow<=7.2.0
  Downloading Pillow-7.2.0.tar.gz (39.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 39.1 MB 54.5 MB/s 
Collecting cloudpickle<1.7.0,>=1.2.0
  Downloading cloudpickle-1.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: future in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pyglet<=1.5.0,>=1.4.0->gym) (0.18.2)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for gym, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for Pillow, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: Pillow, cloudpickle, gym
    Running setup.py install for Pillow ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-04_zwf00/pillow_6f6eee9de0ba4d39860be5d1c9e6fb13/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-04_zwf00/pillow_6f6eee9de0ba4d39860be5d1c9e6fb13/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-8mkbg8ib/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/Pillow
         cwd: /private/tmp/pip-install-04_zwf00/pillow_6f6eee9de0ba4d39860be5d1c9e6fb13/
    
    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
    
    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/private/tmp/pip-install-04_zwf00/pillow_6f6eee9de0ba4d39860be5d1c9e6fb13/setup.py", line 864, in <module>
        setup(
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 165, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/command/install.py", line 546, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/private/tmp/pip-install-04_zwf00/pillow_6f6eee9de0ba4d39860be5d1c9e6fb13/setup.py", line 694, in build_extensions
        raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-install-04_zwf00/pillow_6f6eee9de0ba4d39860be5d1c9e6fb13/setup.py", line 918, in <module>
        raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException:
    
    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
    
    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
    
    
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-04_zwf00/pillow_6f6eee9de0ba4d39860be5d1c9e6fb13/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-04_zwf00/pillow_6f6eee9de0ba4d39860be5d1c9e6fb13/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-8mkbg8ib/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/Pillow Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Before installing gym, you need to install some system packages, like zlib. You can see all packages you need in Ubuntu [here](https://github.com/openai/gym#installing-everything), you might need to google the names to find what they're called in macOS.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have upgraded pip, please remove pillow and gym, and then install them again. If you find it hard, you can do easier with this command:

```
$ pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall Pillow, gym
```

or

```
$ pip install -I Pillow, gym
```

This conflict is because of the old gym version installed on your PC, so it should be force-reinstalled in order to be upgraded. If that doesn't solve the issue and the most recent version of gym needs an older version of Pillow (as I read in your question), then install the corresponding pillow version with this command:

```
$ pip install -I Pillow==7.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked for the answer online and found a solution which works for me. Here it is,

zlib is the dependency to build pillow from source even if you have cached pillow in your site-packages.
What I have done is,

`brew install zlib`
Add zlib libraries to the path, "brew info zlib" gives instructions for how to add zlib libraries as well as package-config file to the path.
For Mac

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib/pkgconfig"
```

`pip install gym`
This worked for me.

Python -> 3.9
Virtualenvironment -> Virtualenv (I haven't tested on conda)

I hope this works for you.

Link: https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/2138

Answer (score 0):

Try without sudo first. if it is still not working you can use pycharm to downloaded it, or use the package and just place it in the folder

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34412603)

Answer (score 0):

I was running Ubuntu and installing python3-dev solved it for me:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

Answer (score -2):

One other solution that worked for me, using conda, was:

```
pip uninstall pillow
pip install pillow
conda install -c conda-forge gym
```